# regexp_instr in Snowflake not working to formulate the CASE statement derived column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a code as below

If `Col1` is `NON-BLANK` and `Col1` includes `"SALES"` and `Col1` does NOT include `"SALES_INTERNAL"` then value the `Col2` as `"ENTERPRISE"` or else value the `Col2` as `"NON_ENTERPRISE"`.

```
CASE 
    WHEN nvl (TABLE."Col1",'NA') <> '' THEN
  CASE
    WHEN regexp_instr (UPPER (TABLE."Col1"), 'SALES') = '0' THEN 'ENTERPRISE' 
    WHEN regexp_instr (UPPER (TABLE."Col1"), 'SALES_INTERNAL') <> '0' THEN 'ENTERPRISE' 
ELSE 'NON_ENTERPRISE'
  END
END AS Col2
```

This does not work in all cases.
Is there any other way to achieve this without `regexp_instr` ?

Thank You

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and show which do/do not work with your code. FYI you can simplify your code by using AND instead of the second WHEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Functions used:

- [CONTAINS()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/contains.html)
- [IFF()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html)

  ```
   WITH CTE AS(SELECT'Some SALES'COL1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL 
   UNION ALL SELECT'SOME SALES_INTERNAL'UNION ALL 
   SELECT'SALES_INTERNAL')


   SELECT 
      COL1, 
      IFF(CONTAINS(COL1,'SALES_INTERNAL')
          ,'ENTERPRISE'
          , IFF(COL1 IS NULL,COL1,'NON_ENTERPRISE')) 
   FROM 
      CTE;
  ```

Comment: I did like below  ``` CASE WHEN T0.COL1 <> ''
 THEN
    IFF (CONTAINS(T0.COL1,'.EXT@ABCD.COM') ,'ENTERPRISE', IFF (CONTAINS (T0.COL1,'@SABCD.COM'),'', 'ENTERPRISE')
        )
  ELSE ''
END AS TEST```

Comment: Awesome work. Next post your answer and then select it as the best solution so if others google for same problem they don’t have to ask a question- just read the best answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction on IFF and contains on snowflake, it resolved my issue